# Editing the URL with user data Python Mechanize

Tags: python, string, parsing, printing, mechanize

I have an URL in Mechanize in Python that reads:

```
members_booking.php?operation=member_day&amp;course_id=1&amp;d_date=2011-10-5&amp;comp=1
```

But I want to change that url depending on the data that the user inputs to the console, eg:

```
year = raw_input("Enter the YEAR")
month = raw_input("Enter the MONTH")
day = raw_input("Enter the DAY")
```

And so that depending on the data the user has inputted in the above code, it will change the url. (where it says d_date=2011-10-5& in the url, I basically want to change it to d_date=year-month-dat&

How do I edit these strings based on the users input? In C (my only point of reference) I would use "d_date=%i-%i-%i&amp", year, month, day       or something to that effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urlstring = "members_booking.php?operation=member_day&course_id=1&d_date=%s-%s-%s&comp=1"

year = raw_input("Enter the YEAR: ")
month = raw_input("Enter the MONTH: ")
day = raw_input("Enter the DAY: ")

print urlstring % (year, month, day)
```